# Style a div with bootstrap table styles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabular

Bootstrap comes with a set of nice styles for a table.

I however need that same style but for a div with table-like content.

I took a look at the css and there's a complicated hierarchy of css selectors that target each tag of the the table. I could update the bootstrap css to target my div but that is messy.

Is there no quick way to apply bootstrap css table styles to my div with .row and .cell inner divs?

Comment: My advice: if it is "table-like" it should be a `table`. If you need a frontend framework that uses `div`s for rendering tables (or tables for rendering `div`s), Bootstrap is not your best choice.

Comment: Tables have no simple way to turn rows into links without js; which is what I need to do.

Comment: What's the problem with JS? If you are using Bootstrap you should be comfortable with it. I love Bootstrap, so I encourage you to use it, even if you have to adapt yourself to its "standards".

Comment: You're making too many assumptions. If you make divs function as links you loose some of the browser's functionality such as a right click menu.

Comment: Tables aren't always a good option. E.g. when logical items span more than one table row, there's no way using tables to group rows, like you can using divs. So the question is valid, sometimes you want to display divs as tables, even though the underlying data doesn't fit into tables.

Answer (score -3):

There are a copious amount of other libraries you can utilize that are much smaller and minimalistic in size.

One of the slimmest variations I've used in the past would be the:

### 960 Grid System

Make a custom CSS file here, without all of the extra necessities of `bootstrap.js`.

#### http://grids.heroku.com/

Learn More:

#### http://960.gs

*It's not exactly a table system, but you can just create full length rows and chalk it up the same way.*

**See here**: http://grids.heroku.com/fluid_grid?column_amount=5